# Connect a model to another model on save in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models

Sorry for my bad english, but I don't even know how to properly describe my problem.

I have 3 models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
     source=models.ForeignKey(Original, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           related_name='book', null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Original(models.Model):

    ...

class Title(models.Model):
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='item', null=True, blank=True)
    original = models.OneToOneField(Original, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='item', null=True, blank=True)
    original_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

In my admin page, when i creating `Book` instance i writing it's name to `Title` model as inline and i want to have an option:

1.Fill in the `original_name` form manually if no source given

2.If source given, leave this field empty,but when saving connect that `Book` instance to `book` field in `Title` model, which is connected to `Original` model instance.

In the end i want to have a `Title` model that have `original_name` and reference to `original` and `book` instances, if `source` given and from which in the future I may refer to the `original_name` when needed

I tried to implement this using `save_model` function, but i have no clue how set `Book` instance as `book` field in `Title` model

I think it must be pretty easy, but i dont know where to start and its frustrating...